# Safely pass HashMap values, without value collection escaping

Tags: java, thread-safety, encapsulation

If I have a hashmap like this:

```
private final Map<String, Collection<String>> descriptions = new HashMap<>();
```

How do I pass the values safely to an alien method?
If I do this:

```
myOtherObject.outputDesc(descriptions.values());
```

then myOtherObject could change the values.

Would this be a safe way of doing this?

```
myOtherObject.outputDesc(new ArrayList<>(descriptions .values()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a copy of the collection as you suggested is a way you could go. But the extra effort for copying the list is not needed. Java provides a more convenient way for [preventing value changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection-java.util.Collection-):

```
myOtherObject.outputDesc(Collections.unmodifiableCollection(descriptions.values()));
```